# PHPUnit @dataProvider simply doesn't work

Tags: php, phpunit

I've read the documentation on the topic, and my code follows all requirements of a data provider implementation. First of all, [here's the full code of the test](http://pastebin.com/tuT9pV9h) just in case it's relevant.

Here's the function implementing data provider:

```
/**
 * Test the createGroup function
 *
 * @return void
 * @author Tomas Sandven <tomas191191@gmail.com>
 *
 * @dataProvider provideFileImportTests_good
 **/
public function testCreateGroup($file, $groupname, $group, $mapping)
{
    // Create a test group
    $id = $this->odm->createGroup($groupname, $group);

    // Try to load it back out
    $result = R::load(OmniDataManager::TABLE_GROUP, $id);

    // Check that the result is not null
    $this->assertFalse(is_null($result));

    return $id;
}
```

PHPUnit just fails:

> Missing argument 1 for tests\broadnet\broadmap\OmniDataManagerTest::testCreateGroup()

I've tried killing the application (`die();`) inside the data provider function, and it never happens. The data provider function is available publicly in the same class, there are no typos in the function name and the `testCreateGroup` function references it in the annotations in the comment, but the data provider function is never called.

Does anybody know why?

Comment: anybody late for the party (as in 2022) : use the setUp( ) function instead of __construct, it's made specifically for phpunit and no need for __construct at all

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Finally after hours of prodding this test file, I discovered that merely defining the constructor function breaks the functionality of data providers. Good to know.

To fix it, just call the parent constructor. Here's how that looked in my case:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Truncate the OmniDataManager tables
    R::wipe(OmniDataManager::TABLE_GROUP);
    R::wipe(OmniDataManager::TABLE_DATA);

    parent::__construct();   // <- Necessary
}
```

---

As [David Harkness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175414/phpunit-dataprovider-simply-doesnt-work/10177489?noredirect=1#comment13064944_10177489) and [Vasily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175414/phpunit-dataprovider-simply-doesnt-work/10177489?noredirect=1#comment49509768_10177489) pointed out in the comments, the constructor override must match the call signature of the base class constructor. In my case the base class constructor didn't require any arguments. I'm not sure if this has just changed in newer versions of phpunit or if it depends on your use case.

In any case, Vasily's example might work better for you:

```
public function __construct($name = null, array $data = array(), $dataName = '')
{
    // Your setup code here

    parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName)
}
```

Comment: Did you also call the parent::__constructor()?  Usually, you wouldn't define a constructor for a testcase anyway, but use the setUp() function.

Comment: I needed some code to be executed once before any of the tests started. No I didn't call `parent::__constructor()`... I replaced the constructor with `function setUpBeforeClass` anyway. It's problematic that it has to be static, but luckily I didn't need to put anything fancy in there

Comment: You can have a custom constructor, but you must take care to accept the same parameters and pass them to the parent constructor.

Comment: `parent::__constructor()` is not a static function call.

Comment: I can confirm that defining a __construct() function breaks dataProvider, even if you call parent::__construct() (not constructor, btw) in your construct function.

Comment: -1 Please either amend this answer or mark Jon Gilberts answer as correct.

Comment: @Hubro Yeah, that's better.

Comment: In my case, as David Harkness has suggested, dataProvider begun to work only after I make the signature of custom constructor the same as parent constructor - public function __construct($name = null, array $data = array(), $dataName = '') and pass all the parameters to parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName).

Comment: Right approach to "setup world" is to use `setUp` or `setUpBeforeClass` methods. See documentation for Phpunit 9.5: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/fixtures.html#fixtures

Answer (score 51):

If you really need it, David Harkness had the right tip. Here's the code:

```
public function __construct($name = NULL, array $data = array(), $dataName = '') {
    $this->preSetUp();
    parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);
}
```

Comment: This specifically solved it for me too, calling parent::construct() with no params did not. Thanks

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thank you!

Comment: Is this constructor define in `KernelAwareTest` class?

Answer (score 21):

To emphasise the point that [micro_user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6141310/micro-user) made, the `@dataProvider` annotation *must* be in a docblock comment. i.e. do this:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider myDataProvider
 *
 */
public function testMyMethod(...)
{
  ...
}
```

Don't do this since it won't work:

```
/*
 * @dataProvider myDataProvider
 *
 */
public function testMyMethod(...)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: you saved a day

Comment: Pleased to hear it. :-)

Comment: you saved another day :)

Comment: After checking almost everything in my project... the solution was so close and so far ;-)
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 15):

For me only removing the constructor has worked. Calling the parent constructor inside my class test broke the annotations as well even with the latest stable version of PHPUnit (6.0.9).

I just moved the code I had on `__constructor` to the `setUp` function that is called before my unit tests run.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that dataProvider is spelled right... `@dataProvidor` vs `@dataProvider`

In the test function which needs a data provider, a docblock is needed which contains

```
/**
* @dataProvider providerItCanTest
*//
```

Comment: This fix/upgrade is now covered by Rector (I wrote): https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/issues/2153

Answer (score 4):

That error means that at least one of the data arrays that your data-provider method is returning is empty.  For example:

```
public function dataProvider() {
    return array(
        array(1, 2, 3),
        array(),           // this will cause a "Missing argument 1" error
        array(4, 5, 6)
    );
}
```

Because you're generating the data arrays dynamically, you'll need to debug your data source(s) and figure out why that would be the case.

Comment: How can the data provider return an empty data array if *it's never called?*

Comment: I copied the provider function into a new test class and it worked. The issue is somewhere else in the class

Comment: @Codemonkey: If the error message you've given comes from a test failure (which I can't tell because you pasted no context), then it can only happen if a data set provided to a test method is empty.  The only other ways I can think of off the top of my head for you to receive such an error message would require you attempting to manually call `testCreateGroup()` yourself from somewhere within your code (and thus, not passing the requisite arguments), or the test being called by PHPUnit without being treated as though it has a data provider (which would indicate a problem in your annotation).

Answer (score 3):

Spent hours trying to figure out what's wrong with dataProvider annotation. It simply wasn't called at all.

In my case problem was opcache. Check php.ini to make sure opcache.save_comments is enabled:

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep opcache.save_comments
```

To enable it add this to php.ini (or /usr/local/php5/php.d/20-extension-opcache.ini in my case because I'm using php for osx from liip.ch):

```
[opcache]
opcache.save_comments=1
```

Comment: This was the issue in my case

Answer (score 1):

Hello to anyone still getting here from google :) I'm using PHP 7.0.5 and PHPUnit 5.3.2.

As @hubro mentions - don't use `__construct()` as it breaks some PHPUnit annotations. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234169/in-phpunit-what-is-the-difference-between-construct-versus-setup) is a SO tread with more details.

My test's class, `MyStuffTest`, extends `MyFancyTestcase` which extends `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`. `MyFancyTestcase` used `__construct()` and I got the same error. It should use `setupBeforeClass()` instead to setup static data shared among all test cases - db connection and such, no need for `__construct()`. DataProvider works now.

Comment: First of all, I'm not saying "don't use `__construct()`", I said that the parent function needs to be called or it will break the functionality of the class. Also, a static setup function can't replace all use cases of `__construct()`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It caused from data provider method visibility is wrong.

I changed my data provider method scope from private to public, and it works.

It is simply mistake, but I waste a lot of time...

From:

```
private function provideFileImportTests_good()
{
   return [
       ...
   ];
}
```

To:

```
public function provideFileImportTests_good()
{
   return [
       ...
   ];
}
```

And it works.