# In phpunit what is the difference between __construct versus setup?

Tags: phpunit

I am curious to know it is good practice to create object in test class __construct or we should always use setup/teardown approach ( or setUpBeforeClass/tearDownAfterClass approach)?

I aware of the fact set/teardown gets called for each test so will it do any good if I put my object creation code in it? e.g.

//mytestclass.php

```
class MyTestClass extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   
    private $obj;
    
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->obj = new FooClass();

    }

   public testFooObj()
   {
     //assertions for $this->obj
   }


   ...

}
```

what could be the issues if I create object in constructor like this:

```
class MyTestClass extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
       
        private $obj;
        
        protected function __construct()
        {
            $this->obj = new FooClass();
    
        }
    
       public testFooObj()
       {
         //assertions for $this->obj
       }
    
   
       ...
    
    }
```

I tried googling around as well as PHPUnit documentation couldn't get much information about,  Can you please help me to understand which one is good practice?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`setUp()` gets called before each of your tests is ran. `__construct()` happens when your class is instantiated. So if you have multiple tests and they use local properties and modify them, using `setUp()` you can ensure that they are the same before each test is ran. The opposite of `setUp()` is `tearDown()` where you can ensure that test data gets cleaned up after each test.

Comment: Thanks @ian, suppose if I am not modifying the local properties, just reading them then which one is better? _construct or setUp? Creating object for each test case wont add bit of overhead?

Comment: It's depends on the nature of your properties and their purpose. If they provide test data then you should use `setUp()`, if they provide anything else (api url, some environment flags, read only params) then you should initialise them else where, constructor is definitely an option. Using `setUp()` is the de facto in PHPUnit for configuring each test, you can think of it as good manners while dealing with the framework. There of course might be an overhead, in which case you can simply check if the property is already set and not re-initialise it again.

Comment: Alternatively, if you move it into constructor nothing bad will happen – you will only get cursed for not following the standard ;)

Comment: Don't implement __construct. If you want to configure your test class for all the test methods, implement setUpBeforeClass.

Comment: @IanBytchek did you test this? PHPUnit 3.7 instantiate the class for each test so __construct is called for each test.

Comment: @danip, that's not what I said. PHPUnit instantiates the class for each test case (not test), that may contain multiple tests. So, it's called only once per test case before any tests are run.

Answer (score 9):

As I have just found out, implementing the default class constructor instead of the setupBeforeClass() method breaks the @dataProvider annotations (probably all kinds of annotations), yielding a "Missing argument" exception for any parameterized tests.

```
Missing argument 1 for AppBundle\Tests\Service\InvitationVerifierTest::testDireccionInvalida()
```

Replacing `public function __construct()` for `public static function setUpBeforeClass()` gets rid of the exception. So there it goes, favor the setupBeforeClass() method over the regular constructor.

PHPUnit version 4.5.0

Comment: I've just seen this behaviour with PHPUnit 5.4.4 too.

Comment: You need to call the parent constructor and pass the three optional parameters: `public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')`.  Then you will not have that problem.  Note that all data providers are called before `setUpBeforeClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the constructor happens in an odd place compared to the `setupBeforeClass()` / `@beforeClass` and `setup()` / `@before`.

If your test has a lot of dependencies, the normal idea is that things in a constructor are only made once. But in PHPUnit, the constructor is called for each test and iteration of a dataProvider. Which means all the dependencies are created again, and again, and again.

If you have an abstract test case for dealing with things for a particular namespace, you can end up with things being very inconsistent or even breaking.

In general, it seems to be recommended to NOT use them.