# ArgumentCountError : Too few arguments to function phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to create some programmed tests using `phpUnit`.
I need to use a Data provider, but every time I try, it throws an error.
I'm even using the example given in the documentation of `phpUnit`.

```
 /**
 * @dataProvider additionWithNonNegativeNumbersProvider
 */
public function testAdd($a, $b, $expected)
{
    $this->assertSame($expected, $a + $b);
}

public function additionWithNonNegativeNumbersProvider()
{
    return [
        [0, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 3]
    ];
}
```

I expect the output to be:

```
There was 1 failure:
1) DataTest::testAdd with data set #3 (1, 1, 3)
Failed asserting that 2 is identical to 3.
```

But it is:

```
ArgumentCountError : Too few arguments to function controllerTests::testAdd(), 0 passed in phar://C:/xampp/htdocs/2019-1-qa-grupo1/myss/Tests/phpunit-8.1.2.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php on line 1172 and exactly 3 expected
 C:\xampp\htdocs\2019-1-qa-grupo1\myss\Tests\controllerTests.php:55
```

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Have you defined a constructor in your test class? That can break things if you don't call the parent constructor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175414/phpunit-dataprovider-simply-doesnt-work

Comment: I have defined my constructor. But it calls the parent constructor. I just realize my IDE says the messsage "Multiple definitions exist for class parent"

Comment: Like it shows in the second answer on that question I linked to? Calling `parent::__construct()` won't work. (Just making sure)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't saw the second answer.

Answer (score 7):

You need to pass the optional arguments to the parent constructor.

If you have this in your test class:

```
<?php
public function __construct() {
    // Some constructor code.
}
```

Change it to:

```
<?php
public function __construct($name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '') {
    parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);
    // Some constructor code.
}
```

Comment: the problem for me was empty constructor in trait. That is a little bit hard to find